# pushNotification to another viewController only show when view is active

Tags: ios, push-notification, viewcontroller

Notification only called the function when `observer_ViewController` is active

AppDelegate.m

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNewShipNotifaction object:ship];
```

observer_ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newShipCome:) name:kNewShipNotifaction object:nil];
} 
- (void)newShipCome:(NSNotification *)notifacation{
  [self updateNotifyWithShip:notifacation.object];
}
```

Notification didn't call the `newShipCome:(NSNotification *)notification` method when I'm in another viewController. When I switched to the `observer_ViewController`, the method still didn't get called.

So...how can I get notification update correctly when I'm not in the `observer_ViewController` ?

Comment: if you want to get the notification event if you are not in the view, that object should be exist in memory. can you provide more info like navigation path how you are moving between views.

Comment: the main container is TabBarController and there is a NavigationController with observer_ViewController

Comment: When I'm in another TabBar's viewController, the newShipCome method didn't got called. When I in the observer_ViewController with NavigationViewController, viewDidLoad got called but I still can't get the object.

Comment: Okey, when you are de-registering the notifications?

Comment: in viewWillDisappear

Comment: Okey, in tabbar controller view did load will call only once, and will disappear will call every time you went to other view, that means that notification is de-registering in and view will appear,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove de-register code form viewWillDisappear it will work